# Restrict days in bootstrap datepicker using checkboxes in submenu

Tags: sub-menu, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

**MY SITUATION**

I've created a submenu in my Custom Post Type. In this submenu, there are 7 checkboxes for each date(Monday till Sunday). I use these boxes for selecting the days my restaurant is closed. For example, I'm closed on Sunday, then I select the checkbox of Sunday and save it with `update_option`.

On my plugin I've created a form with a Bootstrap Datepicker which is working fine. I'm able to disable dates through `daysOfWeekDisabled:[ ]`.

**MY QUESTION**

I want to connect the submenu to my datepicker. My closed days from the checkboxes need to be automatically disabled in my datepicker. I've found an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835247/restrict-days-in-jquery-datepicker-using-checkboxes) for JQuery, but it's not working for me. I hope someone can help me in the right direction

**MY CODE**
*Wordpress submenu/HTML code*

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'reserveringsformulier_add_submenu_gesloten' );
function reserveringsformulier_add_submenu_gesloten() {
add_submenu_page(
'edit.php?post_type=reserveringen',
__( 'Gesloten dagen Restaurant', 'Gesloten dagen' ),
__( 'Gesloten dagen', 'Gesloten dagen' ),
'manage_options',
'gesloten_restaurant',
'gesloten_restaurant_inger_display' );
}

function gesloten_restaurant_inger_display() {

if ($_POST['maandag']=='on') {
$display_maandag = 'checked';
} else {
$display_maandag = '';
} update_option('maandag', $display_maandag);

if ($_POST['dinsdag']=='on') {
  $display_dinsdag = 'checked';
} else {
  $display_dinsdag = '';
} update_option('dinsdag', $display_dinsdag);

if ($_POST['woensdag']=='on') {
  $display_woensdag = 'checked';
} else {
  $display_woensdag = '';
} update_option('woensdag', $display_woensdag);

if ($_POST['donderdag']=='on') {
  $display_donderdag = 'checked';
} else {
  $display_donderdag = '';
} update_option('donderdag', $display_donderdag);

if ($_POST['vrijdag']=='on') {
  $display_vrijdag = 'checked';
} else {
  $display_vrijdag = '';
} update_option('vrijdag', $display_vrijdag);

if ($_POST['zaterdag']=='on') {
  $display_zaterdag = 'checked';
} else {
  $display_zaterdag = '';
} update_option('zaterdag', $display_zaterdag);

if ($_POST['zondag']=='on') {
  $display_zondag = 'checked';
} else {
  $display_zondag = '';
} update_option('zondag', $display_zondag);

?>

<h1><?php _e( 'Gesloten dagen Restaurant Inger', 'gesloten_dagen' ); ?></h1>

<form method="POST" action="">
    <h4>Selecteer de dagen dat het restaurant gesloten is: </h4>

    <table id="selectdays">
    <h4><input type="checkbox" name="maandag" id="maandag" value="1" <?php echo get_option('maandag'); ?> /> Maandag </h4>
    <h4><input type="checkbox" name="dinsdag" id="dinsdag" value="2"<?php echo get_option('dinsdag'); ?> /> Dinsdag </h4>
    <h4><input type="checkbox" name="woensdag" id="woensdag" value="3"<?php echo get_option('woensdag'); ?> /> Woensdag </h4>
    <h4><input type="checkbox" name="donderdag" id="donderdag" value="4"<?php echo get_option('donderdag'); ?> /> Donderdag </h4>
    <h4><input type="checkbox" name="vrijdag" id="vrijdag" value="5"<?php echo get_option('vrijdag'); ?> /> Vrijdag </h4>
    <h4><input type="checkbox" name="zaterdag" id="zaterdag" value="6"<?php echo get_option('zaterdag'); ?> /> Zaterdag </h4>
    <h4><input type="checkbox" name="zondag" id="zondag" value="7"<?php echo get_option('zondag'); ?> /> Zondag </h4>
  </table>
    <p><input type="submit" name="search" value="Opslaan" class="button" /></p>
</form>
```

*footer.php*

```
<script src="../js/moment.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="../locales/bootstrap-datepicker.nl.min.js"></script>

<!--Script voor date en time picker-->
<script>
// Instellingen voor de datetimepicker
$('#mydatepicker1').datepicker({
 language: 'nl',
 startDate: '0',
 endDate: '+1M',
 daysOfWeekDisabled: [1]
 });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**------------ EDIT -> PROBLEM SOLVED ---------**
**MY CODE**
*Wordpress submenu/HTML code*

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'reserveringsformulier_add_submenu_gesloten' );
function reserveringsformulier_add_submenu_gesloten() {
add_submenu_page(
'edit.php?post_type=reserveringen',
__( 'Gesloten dagen Restaurant', 'Gesloten dagen' ),
__( 'Gesloten dagen', 'Gesloten dagen' ),
'manage_options',
'gesloten_restaurant',
'gesloten_restaurant_inger_display' );
}

function gesloten_restaurant_inger_display() {

function gesloten_restaurant_inger_display() {
if (isset($_POST['submit_datum_gesloten'])) {
if (isset($_POST['maandag'])) {
    update_option('maandag', $_POST['maandag']);
    $maandag = $_POST['maandag'];
    //echo 'Uw wijziging is opgeslagen!';
} else {
  delete_option('maandag');
}
$maandag = get_option('maandag');

if (isset($_POST['dinsdag'])) {
    update_option('dinsdag', $_POST['dinsdag']);
    $dinsdag = $_POST['dinsdag'];
    //echo 'Uw wijziging is opgeslagen!';
} else {
  delete_option('dinsdag');
}
$dinsdag = get_option('dinsdag');

if (isset($_POST['woensdag'])) {
    update_option('woensdag', $_POST['woensdag']);
    $woensdag = $_POST['woensdag'];
    //echo 'Uw wijziging is opgeslagen!';
} else {
  delete_option('woensdag');
}
$woensdag = get_option('woensdag');

if (isset($_POST['donderdag'])) {
    update_option('donderdag', $_POST['donderdag']);
    $donderdag = $_POST['donderdag'];
    //echo 'Uw wijziging is opgeslagen!';
} else {
  delete_option('donderdag');
}
$donderdag = get_option('woensdag');

if (isset($_POST['vrijdag'])) {
    update_option('vrijdag', $_POST['vrijdag']);
    $vrijdag = $_POST['vrijdag'];
    //echo 'Uw wijziging is opgeslagen!';
} else {
  delete_option('vrijdag');
}
$vrijdag = get_option('vrijdag');

if (isset($_POST['zaterdag'])) {
    update_option('zaterdag', $_POST['zaterdag']);
    $zaterdag = $_POST['zaterdag'];
    //echo 'Uw wijziging is opgeslagen!';
} else {
  delete_option('zaterdag');
}
$zaterdag = get_option('zaterdag');

if (isset($_POST['zondag'])) {
    update_option('zondag', $_POST['zondag']);
    $zondag = $_POST['zondag'];
    //echo 'Uw wijziging is opgeslagen!';
} else {
  delete_option('zondag');
}
$zondag = get_option('zondag');
echo 'Uw wijziging is opgeslagen!';
}

?>

<h1><?php _e( 'Gesloten dagen Restaurant Inger', 'gesloten_dagen' ); ?></h1>

    <h1><?php _e( 'Gesloten dagen Restaurant Inger', 'gesloten_dagen' ); ?></h1>
<form method="POST" action="">
  <h4>Selecteer de dagen dat het restaurant gesloten is: </h4>
      <h4><input type="checkbox" name="maandag" id="maandag" value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['maandag'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> /> Maandag </h4>
      <h4><input type="checkbox" name="dinsdag" id="dinsdag" value="2" <?php if(isset($_POST['dinsdag'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> /> Dinsdag </h4>
      <h4><input type="checkbox" name="woensdag" id="woensdag" value="3" <?php if(isset($_POST['woensdag'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> /> Woensdag </h4>
      <h4><input type="checkbox" name="donderdag" id="donderdag" value="4" <?php if(isset($_POST['donderdag'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> /> Donderdag </h4>
      <h4><input type="checkbox" name="vrijdag" id="vrijdag" value="5" <?php if(isset($_POST['vrijdag'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> /> Vrijdag </h4>
      <h4><input type="checkbox" name="zaterdag" id="zaterdag" value="6" <?php if(isset($_POST['zaterdag'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> /> Zaterdag </h4>
      <h4><input type="checkbox" name="zondag" id="zondag" value="0" <?php if(isset($_POST['zondag'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> /> Zondag </h4>
  <p><input type="submit" name="submit_datum_gesloten" value="Opslaan" class="button" /></p>
</form>
```

*footer.php*

```
<script src="../js/moment.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="../locales/bootstrap-datepicker.nl.min.js"></script>

<!--Script voor date en time picker-->
<script>
var disableDates = "<?php echo
    $maandag = get_option('maandag');
    $dinsdag = get_option('dinsdag');
    $woensdag = get_option('woensdag');
    $donderdag = get_option('donderdag');
    $vrijdag  = get_option('vrijdag');
    $zaterdag = get_option('zaterdag');
    $zondag = get_option('zondag');
    echo $maandag . $dinsdag . $woensdag . $donderdag . $vrijdag . $zaterdag . $zondag ?>";
//alert(disableDates);
// Instellingen voor de datetimepicker
$('#mydatepicker1').datepicker({
language: 'nl',
startDate: '0',
endDate: '+2M',
daysOfWeekDisabled: disableDates
});

</script>
```

Thanks in advance.